# node passport routes only authenticated users can access

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to secure certain routes so that only authenticated users can access them.  I am using passport.js for authentication.

in my index.js file I have the below route I would like to make available only to authenticated users (there will be additional checks later to ensure authorization).

```
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
const adminContlr = require('../controllers/admins');
const editProduct = adminContlr.editProduct

router.get('/products/edit/:id', editProduct);
```

in the admins controller

```
// get the edit form
module.exports.editProduct = 
    (req , res , next) => {

        let id = req.params.id;

        // do stuff
    };
```

in config/auth.js I have a helper function to check if a user is authenticated.

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function (req, res, next) {
        // isAuthenticated comes from passport
        if (req.isAuthenticated) {
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error', 'Please login');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

In most examples I have seen they do something like this below.

```
router.get('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('admins', { title: "Admin" });
});
```

But because my function is in a separate file than my route it doesn't seem to work like this.

```
router.get('/products/edit/:id', ensureAuthenticated, editProduct);
```

I suppose I could add something like this to all of my route functions that I want to secure where I'm checking if req.isAuthenticated but I was hoping for an easier way by using the helper function.

```
   if (req.isAuthenticated) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
    req.flash('error', 'Please login');
    res.redirect('/login'); 
   }
```

**update**
I'm wondering if something may be wrong with my auth.js because it doesn't even work when I use it like this

```
router.get('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('admin');
});
```

Comment: how do you import `ensureAuthenticated` function into file where admin route is?

Comment: const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

Comment: Do you any error message?

Comment: no errors, it just lets the unauthenticated user access the route.